# C# - Adding new Textblocks to Grid RowDefinition programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make an application which reads out RSS feeds and shows them in an WPF form. To separate the posts I am using a grid and add 2 more RowDefinitions (one for the title and one for the subject).

Currently I am stuck. I want to add some Textblocks to the Rows that I just defined, but I have no idea how because they don't have names. Does anyone have an idea?

What I currently have:

```
        //defining Grid
        Grid post = new Grid();
        post.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        post.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        post.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        post.ShowGridLines = true;
        post.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        {
            Width = new GridLength(500)
        });

        //loop trough all RSS feeds
        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            //add rows for title and Summary
            post.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
            {
                Height = new GridLength(50),

            });
            post.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
            {
                Height = new GridLength(50)
            });

            //Grid.SetRow(TitleTextblock, 0);
            //Grid.SetRow(SummaryTextblock, 1);

            //fills textblocks
            post.Children.Add(new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = item.Title.Text                  
            });
            post.Children.Add(new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = item.Summary.Text
            });
        }
        //show grid on window
        this.Content = post;
```

which results in: 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Quw.png)

Comment: If you set the `Column` and `Row` of the dynamic TextBlock it should add it in there. Not sure what the problem is,  can you elaborate?

Comment: Why are you using a Grid, instead of just adding TextBlocks to a StackPanel? That said, you should consider using an ItemsControl instead of creating UI elements in code behind. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: @FreekW. I have added a screenshot with the result to the main question. it places all Textblocks on top of each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, it looks like a problem with setting your `Definitions` correctly:

```
//defining Grid
    Grid post = new Grid();
    post.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    post.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    post.Margin = new Thickness(10);
    post.ShowGridLines = true;
    post.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
    {
        Width = new GridLength(500)
    });

    //add local field to keep track of what row you're on
    int rowdeff = 0;

    //loop trough all RSS feeds
    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        //add rows for title and Summary
        post.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        {
            Height = new GridLength(50),

        });
        post.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        {
            Height = new GridLength(50)
        });

        //create the textblocks
        TextBlock TitleTextblock = new TextBlock;
        TextBlock SummaryTextblock = new TextBlock;

        //add content to textblocks
        TitleTextBlock.Text = item.Title.Text;
        SummaryTextblock.Text = item.Summary.Text;

        //set definitions
        Grid.SetColumn(TitleTextblock, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(SummaryTextblock, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(TitleTextblock, rowdeff);
        Grid.SetRow(SummaryTextblock, rowdeff);

        //fills textblocks
        post.Children.Add(TitleTextBlock);
        post.Children.Add(SummaryTextblock);

        //add next row
        rowdeff++;
    }
    //show grid on window
    this.Content = post;
```

Comment: Yes, that did it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, 0);
```

Hope this helps you